# YouTube API error uploading a video using name@company account

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

Im trying to upload a video to youtube through the api. I set everything up right and it worked fine on my personal account. I ran through the process to gain the client id and secret ( using their Oauth verification ) and im getting the following error.

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "youtube.header",
"reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
}
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Unauthorized"
}
}
```

I have been researching it and it seems it might be because the gmail account im using ( my clients ) is name@company.com opposed to name@gmail.com. I keep seeing reference to this cannot be a service account but im unsure what that is.

Any idea what is causing this and if it is possible to use their company account to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: I put php in there because this is built on Laravel and if someone had a work around I figured they would need to know what it was built on. If you could kindly give me the link to the duplicate question I can just get my answer from there. I have reviewed more then 25 questions similiar but non have had the exact same problem as me.

Comment: The link is at the top of your question.

Comment: That did the trick. I just wasnt searching with the right terms. Thanks for pointing it out.